# Factorizing Cubic equation into quadratic and linear equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If it is given that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of :

## $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$

How can we write the above equation as

## $\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(ax+d\right)=0$

Where did the 'b' and 'c' dissappear.

Comment: Expand to find

$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=ax^3+(a+d)x^2+(a+d)x+d\implies b=c=a+d$$

Comment: lab bhattacharjee - thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^2+x+1$ is a factor of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, there exist $(e,f)$ such that $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=(x^2+x+1)(ex+f)$$
$$\iff ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=ex^3+(e+f)x^2+(e+f)x+f$$
From this, we have
$$a=e,b=e+f,c=e+f,d=f\Rightarrow b=c=a+d.$$
Hence, we have
$$\begin{align}ax^3+bx^2+cx+d&=ax^3+(a+d)x^2+(a+d)x+d\\&=ax(x^2+x+1)+d(x^2+x+1)\\&=(x^2+x+1)(ax+d).\end{align}$$

Comment: Aah that explains it, I figured out the 4th equation but never knew that b=c=(a+d). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HijazAslam: You are welcome.